# Incorrect label representation with gvisTimeline in the R googleVis

Tags: r, googlevis

I am using `gvisTimeline` for performing Gantt charts, and think that this library is brilliant.
But when the `barlabel` parameter  in `gvisTimeline` function is set to dataframe column name, which contains Russian words, they comes into `��������`, when plotting this timeline.

I've tried changing encoding to UTF-8, but as a result I receive the same question marks and also something like `<ce><f2><e1><ee><f0> <ef><f0><ee><e1>`. 
So I guess the problem is with encoding, but I have no idea how to fix it.

The same names in `plotly` or `ggplot2` diagrams are displayed correctly.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.